# How to Change the language of my JDateChooser?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jcalendar

I would like to change the language of my `JDateChooser` to Chinese.
I have tried this method:

```
//change jdatelanguage
Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN");
```

But it didn't work. Maybe I put it in the wrong place.

Can someone please help?

I also tried this method:

java -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR -cp build/classes DateDemo

Comment: Did you try calling `JDateChooser#setLocale`? - It would also help to know which `JDateChooser` you're using :P

Comment: How do I call JDateChooser#setLocale? I am usingJcalendar 1.4. Thank you!

Comment: From [JCalendar Tutorial](http://flib.sourceforge.net/JCalendar/doc/tutorial.html) - *"The JCalendar components take advantage of the internationalization and localization work done by the Calendar class. In order to fully localize JCalendar to other than US English, you will need to obtain the source code for JCalendar and create a org.freixas.jcalendar.Bundle_<locale>.properties file which translates the text in org.freixas.jcalendar.Bundle.properties, where <locale> is a two-letter country code."*

Comment: Have you tried `JLocaleChooser`?